# SlimFramework does not work on Synology DS16+II

Tags: php, slim, synology

I have already created a REST-API with SlimFramework which is hosted on XAMPP local on my PC. It is working perfect on my PC but when i want to put it on my “Live System” Synology NAS (Synology DS216+II) it always gives me an Error 404 and i have no clue why.

On my Synology NAS (Synology DS216+II) there is a Apache Server running (Version 2.2)
Since i know that my API does not work on the Synology i tried to implement the “demo” example at https://www.slimframework.com/
Code:

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
//$name = $request->getAttribute('name');
$response->getBody()->write("Hello, test");

return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

[This happens when i want to call this code on my synology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HfTL.png)

[This happens when i want to call this code on my PC (XAMPP)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7siV.png)

But why am I getting this Error on my Synology?

I would be happy about some help

Comment: Did you check your apache access logs? What does your apache config look like?

Comment: i have tried to find the apache access logs but i just found the apache22-error_log

Can you tell me where these access logs are ?

Comment: You can find the info in your config, I think it should be somewhere like /etc/apache/httpd.conf. Just run: `cat /etc/apache/httpd.conf | grep _log` and it should show you were the access and error logs are stored. Usually it's in /var/log/apache/error.log

Comment: no "apache" does not exist in etc,

the apache22-error_log was in var/log/httpd

Comment: Is there an access log as well? It would be interesting to see if the 404 comes from your apache, as it looks like a custom designed one instead of the default page. So it might be a different server/vhost is setup there. It would be helpful if you can locate the config for your apache. If your configuration is not inside /etc/ you might have to check where your nas keeps the configuration. This can vary based on the linux distribution it's based on. In there you should have configs that contain text snippets you have to look for like DocumentRoot to see from which folder it reads the data.

Comment: Have you tried this setup? https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2